# Milnor Number of real and imaginary parts of holomorphic germs?

Tags: analytic-functions, several-complex-variables, singularity, singularity-theory

By performing some computations using the Singular software, I've noticed the following pattern: if $\mu$ is the Milnor Number of a holomorphic germ $f\in \mathcal{O}_n$ at the origin, then the Milnor Number of its real and imaginary parts are equal and are $\mu^2$, that is,
$$
\mu_{(\mathcal{R}e(f),0)} = \mu_{f,0}^2  
$$

By Milnor number of the real part of $f$, I mean $u=\mathcal{R}e(f)$ as a germ of real analytic function of $2n$ real variables (the real and imaginary parts of each complex variable). If $\mathcal{A_{2n}}$ is the ring of germs of such real analytic functions, then
$$
\mu_{(\mathcal{R}e(f),0)}=\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\mathcal{A}_{2n}}{\left<\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_n}\right> }
$$

I've noticed the same happens for the imaginary part of $f$.

I would like to know if there's any generalisation to this. I've tried using some direct sum properties on ideals but got nowhere. I suspect there might be some tensor products involved, but also got nowhere.

Comment: $\mathcal{Im}(f)$ provides the same Milnor number due to Cauchy-Riemann. My guess for a proof would be: Extent $\mathcal{Re}(f)$ to a holomorphic function $g$ in $2n$ variables and try to compare the milnor numbers of $f$ and $g$. I think you have $\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes \mathbb{C} = \mathcal{O}_{2n}$.

Are you sure about $\mu_{(\mathcal{R}e(f),0)} = \mu_{f,0}^2$? I would expect $\mu_{(\mathcal{R}e(f),0)} = 2\mu_{f,0}$

Comment: @TomTom314 I'm positive about the squared Milnor number, just re-did an example. Take the function $f(x,y)=xy^2+x^2y$, $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$. Its Milnor Number at the origin is 4 and the MIlnor number of its real and imaginary parts is 16. I have some other examples too. It also fails to be the double if you take a simples singularity like $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ in which you'll get $1^2=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a partial solution, i.e. I'll prove the formula for the complex milnor number of $Re(f)$:

For two germs $f\in\mathcal{O}_{k,0}$, $g\in\mathcal{O}_{l,0}$ with isolated singularities we can define $f+g\in\mathcal{O}_{k+l,0}$ and we have $\mu_{f+g}=\mu_f\cdot \mu_g$. Outline of a proof: Take morsifications $f_\epsilon,g_\delta$. Then $f_\epsilon+g_\delta$ is a morsifications of $f+g$ and the non-degenerated singularities are given by the cartesian product of the singularities of $f_\epsilon$ and $g_\delta$.

Let $g\in\mathcal{O}_{2n,0}$ the complex extension of $Re(f)$, whereby $x,y$ denote the coordinates corresponding to the real/imaginary parts of $f$. Then we can write $2g= f(x+iy)+\tilde f(x-iy)$ ($\tilde f$ is the germ we get by conjugation of the coefficients). Applying the above mentions result we get $\mu_{Re(f)}=\mu_{f(x+iy)}\cdot\mu_{\tilde f(x-iy)} = \mu_f^2$.

Remark on coordinates. Define $u_k:=x_k+iy_k, v_k:=x_k-iy_k$. We get $2x_k=u_k+v_k$ and $2iy_k=u_k-v_k$. Therefore we have a change of coordinates and we get $2g(x,y)=f(u)+f(v)$, such that the formula for the Milnor number is applicable.

It remains to show $\mu^\mathbb{R}_{Re(f)} =\mu^\mathbb{C}_{Re(f)}$. Unfortunately we have only $\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb {C}\subset \mathcal{O}_{2n}$, whereby $\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb {C}$ is dense in $\mathcal{O}_{2n}$.

To show $\mu^\mathbb{R}_{Re(f)} =\mu^\mathbb{C}_{Re(f)}$ I would try
$$
\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\mathcal{A}_{2n}}{\left<\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_n}\right> } = \\
\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} \dfrac{\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C}}{\left<\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_n}\right> } = \\
\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} \dfrac{\mathcal{O}_{2n}}{\left<\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_n}\right> }
$$
The first equality follows from some properties on tensor product (Didn't checked it in detail).

For the second equality we need to do some more work. if we compare the rings $\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C}\subset \mathcal{O}_{2n}$ we have for $f\in\mathcal{O}_{2n}$: $f\in \mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ iff the coefficients of the power series splits into finite many subset such that the coefficients in a subset only differ by a real factor, i.e. we have a finite sum $f=\sum c_k f_k$ with $f_k\in\mathcal{A}_{2n}, c_k\in\mathbb{C}$.

The two rings are both local and the maximal ideals ($\mathfrak{m}$) are genereate by the same elements. Therefore we have $(\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C})/\mathfrak{m}^k=\mathcal{O}_{2n}/\mathfrak{m}^k$ because they have finite $\mathbb{C}$-dimension. If we know $\mu^{\mathbb{R}}<\infty$ (*) we can choose $k\gg 1$ such that
$$ \dfrac{\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C}}{\left<\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_n}\right> } = 
\dfrac{(\mathcal{A}_{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C})/\mathfrak{m}^k}{\left<\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_n}\right> }
$$
and the same for $\mathcal{O}_{2n}$ and we get $\mu^\mathbb{R}_{Re(f)} =\mu^\mathbb{C}_{Re(f)}$.

(*) If we can show $\mu^{\mathbb{C}}<\infty \Rightarrow \mu^{\mathbb{R}}<\infty$ the proof would be complete.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll take a throughout look on it. To show that $\mu_{Re(f)}^\mathbb{R} = \mu_{Re(f)}^\mathbb{C}$ isn't it enough to write the partial derivatives in $^\mathbb{C}$ as the partial derivatives respective to the real and imaginary parts of each coordinate?

Comment: Also, when you stated that $\mu_{f+g}=\mu_f\cdot \mu_g$, I understood that they have different sets of coordinates, but when using this on $\mu_{Re(f)}$, won't $f(x+iy)$ and $\tilde{f}(x-iy)$ share coordinates?

Comment: @Marra: I added some remarks on the product formula and the separation of coordinates. Hopefully this explains it somewhat better. I didn't get your question on $\mu^\mathbb{R}=\mu^\mathbb{C}$. Here I added my train of thougths pointing to the hurdles as I see them.

Comment: On the part of the asterisk ($\mu^\mathbb{C}<\infty \Rightarrow \mu^\mathbb{R}<\infty$ ), that's for $Re(f)$, right?

Comment: Yes, everything below "It remains to show $\mu^\mathbb{R}_{Re(f)} =\mu^\mathbb{C}_{Re(f)}$" refers to $Re(f)$ and $g$. I've read a little of the proof "isolated singularity $\Rightarrow \mu<\infty$ in "W. EbelingFunctions of Several Complex Variables and Their Singularities". I got the impression that it can be reworked for the real case. But I'm not really familar with real singularities.

Comment: I appreciate all the effort you've put into this. Singularities are not my area (I'm in holomorphic foliations) but I'm trying to work with normal forms for some singular Levi-flat hypersurfaces and some singularities appear often. I will try to find Ebeling's book and see it for myself. And again, thanks for everything :)